# Loading an Array to TableView based on Segment-Control

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am relatively new to Swift. I tried to search and google the problem but i can't find any answers. It shouldn't be that hard. Hope you guys can help me out. I‘ve been struggling with this Issue over days now:

I created a Tableview which loads an array of tuples from another .swift file. That is working fine! Now I want the tableview to choose the .swift based on a "segment control". So if the Segment-Control is switched to "A" I want it to show the Array of "PSSCBOOKMac.Swift", for B it would be the Array of "PSSCBOOKWin.swift".

The Action ist written properly, I guess (print-statements are working). But the change of the segment-control doesn't effect the Tableview. My guess: The segment-control doesn't effect the Tableview because it has been loaded before and I can't change the value. How can I achieve that?

Cheers for any answers!

Here is the Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var PSSCSegmentControl: UISegmentedControl!

    //LOAD ARRAY FROM PSSCBOOK.SWIFT
    var PSSCBook = PSSCBOOKMac()

    @IBAction func PSSCSegmentControlChoose(sender: AnyObject) {
        if PSSCSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            var PSSCBook = PSSCBOOKMac()
            println("im mac")
        } else {
            var PSSCBook = PSSCBOOKWin()
            println("im win")
        }
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return PSSCBook.PSSCTools.count
        } else {
            return PSSCBook.PSSCFile.count
        }
    }   

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PSCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let (shortCutTitle,shortCutKey) = PSSCBook.PSSCTools[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = shortCutTitle
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = shortCutKey
        } else {
            let (shortCutTitle,shortCutKey) = PSSCBook.PSSCFile[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = shortCutTitle
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = shortCutKey
        }

        /*  var PSIcon = UIImage(named: "PSIcon")
        cell.imageView?.image = PSIcon */

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section == 0 {
            return "Tools"
        } else {
            return "File"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you update the datasource of your table view, it won't magically update itself.

You have to reload the table view for the changes to take place:

```
@IBAction func PSSCSegmentControlChoose(sender: AnyObject) {
    if PSSCSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        var PSSCBook = PSSCBOOKMac()
        println("im mac")
    } else {
        var PSSCBook = PSSCBOOKWin()
        println("im win")
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That sounds very logical. Unfortunately xcode shows me an error in the "self.tableView.reloadData();" line. It says: Cannot Invoke "reloadData" with no arguments..An ideas

Comment: Have you tried maybe googling the error instead of just waiting for someone to solve your problem? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733126/swift-cannot-invoke-reloaddata-with-no-arguments)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I usually do that as well. Thought I missed a detail of some sort. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I spend the last two days trying to figure out what was wrong with my code. I implemented the suggested reloadData() without having errors. The println Values in the console change.. But the tableview just won't refresh. I really don’t know where else to look, is searched for hours. Could somebody please tell me what type of silly mistake I am doing? Thanks guys!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
//LOAD ARRAY FROM PSSHORTCUTSBOOK.SWIFT

var PSSCBook = PSShortCutsBook()

@IBOutlet weak var SCOutlet: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var SCtableviewOutlet: UITableView!

@IBAction func SCAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    if SCOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        var PSSCBook = PSShortCutsBook()
        println("There are \(PSSCBook.shortCutsPS.count) items in this Array")
        self.SCtableviewOutlet.reloadData();
    } else {
        var PSSCBook = PSShortCutsBook2()
        println("There are \(PSSCBook.shortCutsPS.count) items in this Array")
        self.SCtableviewOutlet.reloadData();
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return PSSCBook.shortCutsPS.count
    } else {
        return PSSCBook.shortCutsPS2.count
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PSCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let (shortCutTitle,shortCutKey) = PSSCBook.shortCutsPS[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = shortCutTitle
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = shortCutKey
    } else {
        let (shortCutTitle,shortCutKey) = PSSCBook.shortCutsPS2[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = shortCutTitle
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = shortCutKey
    }
  /*  var PSIcon = UIImage(named: "PSIcon")
    cell.imageView?.image = PSIcon */
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 0 {
        return "Tools"
    } else {
        return "Help"
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```