# Swift - "must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I keep getting this error message. I have already tried to add this in my code:

`self.collectionView.register(UICollectionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")`

But that just brings up the another error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)'

Here is my code:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController,     UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var UICollectionView: UICollectionView!

let items = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.UICollectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    super.viewDidLoad()
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.mainListLabel.text = items[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: So do you have a table view or collection view? Your code shows collection view, but then why are you calling `tableView.register`?

Comment: Adding to Davids comment, you register a table view cell with identifier "cell" and you dequeue a collection view cell with identifier "Cell"

Comment: sorry I just copied the snippet. I tried it with collectionView.regester. Just updated it

Comment: @NicolasElPapu I updated that was well. Same error

Comment: You are also trying to register the UITableViewCell class into your collection view, instead of what you are trying to dequeue "CollectionViewCell"

Comment: Updated it again :D same error

Comment: what is the prober way to register the collection view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
self.collectionView.register(UICollectionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

to

```
self.collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

And

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
```

What's the `CollectionViewCell` stands for? It's derived class or something?

Because you register `UICollectionCell` but call `CollectionViewCell` ?

I hope it works.

// edit

Final Solution:

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var mainListButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var mainListLabel: UILabel!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
super.init(frame: frame)

self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}


required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
super.init(coder: coder)

self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}

}
```

Set your custom collection view class or use XIB.

Comment: You mean `self.collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")`. If the force cast is expected to ever succeed, you need to register the actual type, not its superclass.

Comment: Hey @DávidPásztor actually you're right. But I mean there's 3 diffrent class using. `UICollectionCell`, `UICollectionViewCell` and `CollectionViewCell`. And I think there's no need to use force cast because if-let, guard is so superful to use I think.

Comment: CollectionViewCell is a Subclass I created. Idk but thats how it was done in the Tutorials and there I also have my label-outlet. Anyway I changed the register code as you said, but I still get the "ambigious reference..." error :(

Comment: is your UICollectionView dragged from storyboard or created programmatically?

Comment: @elia doesn't matter how you do the actual casting, if you register a superclass, the cell will be of the superclass, so you won't be able to cast it to a subclass.

Comment: So What do I have to do ?

Comment: @Chris are you using storyboard? If so, did you connected your variable correctly? Can you look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323153/ambiguous-reference-to-member-collectionview-numberofitemsinsection-when-r

Comment: I updated my code. Where do I have to call the new Outlet now?

Comment: `@IBOutlet weak var UICollectionView: UICollectionView!`UICollectionView cannot be a variable name. It might be like `@IBOutlet weak var yourCollectionView: UICollectionView!` I guess

Comment: Im getting another error now. "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key collectionView."

Comment: I dont think the name is the problem

Comment: Did you delegate and set data source of collection view with drag and drop in storyboard?

Comment: @Chris and check out maybe you had use a collectionView and then removed it and newly used a new one. Check out connections I mean.

Comment: yep that was it. Im getting close now :D "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" new error.

Comment: is that error for collectionView or a for a wrongly used optional value ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201263/discussion-between-chris-and-elia).